# Растянуть div на всю высоту страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, background

Имеется код:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="main">
    <!-- Какое-то содержимое-->
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="background-overlay"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.background{
    background: url("img/background.png") fixed no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(5px);
}
.background-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Цель – растянуть div и его background на всю высоту страницы, при заполнении страницы содержимым в какой-то момент высоты картинки не хватает и ниже появляется белый фон.
Менял % на vh – не помогло...
При этом сам div "обрывается" вместе с картинкой[image: "Обрыв" div]

Comment: `.main {min-height: 100vh}`

Comment: Браузер Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

> Цель – растянуть div и его background на всю высоту

В вопросе не указано, о каком именно `div` идёт речь, поэтому придётся угадывать.

У Вас элемент `.background` установлен абсолютно позиционированным.

Чтобы он занимал всю высоту элемента `.main`, нужно для `.main` задать свойство `position: relative`.

---

**Результат:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  background: url("img/background.png") fixed no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.background-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis asperiores quas eligendi. Facere numquam sint, deserunt beatae veritatis illo hic assumenda vero iure quam maxime non iste quasi labore voluptas exercitationem, odio quia, animi unde sapiente
  delectus ducimus! Quam inventore nemo blanditiis, aliquid voluptatum ab illo corrupti. Assumenda, eaque. Porro suscipit quod doloremque fugiat? Laborum debitis consequuntur vitae eaque accusamus quibusdam inventore commodi architecto eligendi? Beatae
  reprehenderit laboriosam recusandae omnis neque, voluptas eum suscipit, corporis, quo ut porro dolorum in officiis ipsum expedita id placeat voluptatem laudantium magni totam minus. Similique quis, voluptates consectetur sequi commodi deleniti, sunt
  minus nostrum inventore natus dicta dolor dolore iure vitae libero mollitia quibusdam ducimus, ex nam? Reprehenderit cupiditate sit explicabo ipsum suscipit distinctio animi molestias, placeat, quas voluptatem accusamus. Aperiam aliquam consectetur
  culpa inventore nihil quia atque commodi. Ipsa veritatis quia dolor quidem id similique doloremque amet! Voluptas, ullam soluta officiis doloremque eum nulla, totam dicta sequi, dolorem dolorum tenetur accusantium vero aliquid sapiente repudiandae fuga
  placeat explicabo iusto deleniti quibusdam. Nisi, aut molestias officia ea architecto voluptatem. Aperiam repellat alias ut autem sit placeat odio similique dolor repellendus eos, velit esse itaque delectus rem voluptate quia laboriosam sapiente dicta
  ullam, tenetur accusamus soluta cumque? Eum consequatur et, nihil magni ipsa eius odio ipsam, minima mollitia nemo veniam architecto assumenda. Ipsa dolore nihil ab. Corrupti necessitatibus optio numquam deserunt ut, praesentium nemo rem dolor, maiores
  officia consequuntur, aspernatur recusandae! Quis sunt eos rem explicabo beatae atque, ducimus aperiam laborum illum maxime natus inventore error qui doloribus deleniti esse vel odio quia. Dolorem, dolores, at harum fugit perspiciatis ab, tenetur illo
  minima explicabo nihil provident magni cum nemo fuga? Animi porro saepe, vel iste expedita reiciendis quod voluptatem recusandae repellendus maxime vitae optio consequatur magnam ducimus eligendi eveniet cupiditate quasi totam possimus blanditiis? Veniam
  modi tenetur facere quasi, reprehenderit asperiores minus perspiciatis delectus consequatur esse eligendi odit officiis rem consequuntur sunt amet voluptas? Libero est, ipsum deleniti fugiat ab quam enim. Doloribus inventore illum magnam ipsam ut dolorum
  perferendis voluptatibus! Aspernatur eligendi consequatur culpa fuga saepe, laboriosam praesentium, odio obcaecati deleniti distinctio sapiente ratione excepturi sint corrupti! Nihil quaerat praesentium nemo sit earum placeat perspiciatis. Officia illo
  vitae minus expedita, voluptatem, odit reiciendis illum pariatur sunt fuga doloribus iste ad rerum voluptatibus molestias eligendi voluptates consequatur facere et repellendus! Dolores neque culpa molestias quae sit. Dolore repellat cum omnis totam
  unde impedit laudantium placeat nesciunt beatae vitae ullam odit sunt eligendi maxime, obcaecati veniam architecto rerum eos! Soluta ut consequatur eos! Natus, temporibus a doloribus fugiat explicabo nobis nulla sed, vel dignissimos rerum vitae odit
  sint culpa quisquam iste asperiores totam amet libero, aspernatur porro necessitatibus impedit. Consequuntur earum dolore nostrum provident commodi, explicabo tempora consectetur ipsa nihil velit nobis pariatur ex iusto? Eligendi aliquid dolore excepturi
  unde, voluptates magni animi! Eveniet ullam, sed nisi obcaecati dolorum deserunt fugit eos sequi recusandae atque soluta placeat reprehenderit mollitia veniam molestiae, amet tempora labore repudiandae, ipsum earum doloremque maxime. Fuga ex fugiat
  repudiandae, voluptates totam atque nesciunt minus, dolore doloribus hic quaerat vero a voluptatibus voluptate vitae veritatis unde itaque libero et, incidunt quis at delectus rem. Cum quae assumenda alias repellat illum, quas tempora doloremque quos
  vel deserunt repellendus vitae debitis aspernatur eum mollitia architecto ea cupiditate ullam natus voluptas necessitatibus, deleniti quia. Architecto, harum cupiditate, aliquam tempore magnam velit in aspernatur repellat earum blanditiis quam reprehenderit
  nam incidunt error vitae dolor natus aut, asperiores at. Temporibus hic dicta beatae numquam, quidem, voluptas delectus consequuntur cupiditate quaerat quam aliquid, sed qui fuga maxime! Dolorem, deleniti fugit harum amet enim nesciunt magnam corporis
  voluptatibus eveniet iste mollitia ipsum itaque? Aliquid, amet expedita iste facere alias eaque nihil! Veritatis neque, quae non repudiandae libero voluptas soluta excepturi odit sit nesciunt nisi nulla similique reiciendis assumenda corporis sapiente.
  Eius deleniti officiis, dolore sunt sapiente rerum, ad, veniam quo beatae voluptatibus libero magnam in facere excepturi. Quis labore, eveniet dicta rem debitis dolore amet eaque est sapiente praesentium voluptatibus, consectetur consequuntur architecto
  nesciunt ipsam doloribus asperiores possimus delectus, harum aspernatur accusamus. Laudantium harum voluptate eius quisquam! Animi cum libero officiis temporibus reprehenderit illo officia quidem vel aliquam dicta magnam ex, velit, distinctio voluptatem
  at. Sapiente beatae, et dolorem ut quia veniam excepturi nulla deserunt illum culpa repellendus nostrum quaerat fugiat quis nisi, ipsum nemo reprehenderit vero iusto nam velit consequatur ipsa. Quod, ullam nemo maiores, aspernatur qui animi alias ducimus
  architecto doloremque fuga consequuntur quis consectetur. Aliquid recusandae aut tenetur iure eum natus omnis ut minus. Illum dolore possimus quam consequatur, quis at nulla reprehenderit distinctio. Necessitatibus aut corporis harum consectetur fugiat
  numquam quaerat perferendis illo velit nemo vel deleniti porro sed laboriosam, assumenda sunt reprehenderit excepturi ullam quasi ab voluptate non similique laborum cupiditate. Provident, reprehenderit officiis? Quas nisi ipsa in non sed voluptas fugit
  nobis enim architecto amet ex recusandae itaque, alias impedit, hic, quibusdam expedita doloribus mollitia nesciunt ducimus tempore eos culpa. Omnis eum repudiandae ipsum enim laborum, nobis dolor temporibus reiciendis distinctio, ullam, minima natus.
  Recusandae consequatur doloribus distinctio corrupti placeat molestias aliquam numquam, vero perferendis quasi at dolore deserunt quam maxime ut minus optio excepturi similique? Et adipisci sint similique repellat recusandae corrupti, molestiae labore
  reiciendis veritatis natus cupiditate explicabo sunt dolorum dignissimos expedita esse est! Consequuntur tempore et, voluptas asperiores sint at perferendis omnis itaque repellendus vitae. Ipsam placeat magni, modi veritatis sed, praesentium omnis,
  id voluptate cumque similique necessitatibus perferendis ipsa reiciendis? Corporis ipsum magnam exercitationem incidunt voluptatem, ullam voluptates nobis obcaecati veritatis. Ab inventore labore autem neque incidunt numquam facere amet, quod vel nulla,
  nisi voluptas quidem voluptate quo perspiciatis tenetur eos ducimus quos? Cumque voluptates iste officiis vitae cupiditate, natus itaque illum suscipit voluptatem iure perspiciatis doloribus harum nesciunt odio. Minus aperiam tenetur, corrupti eaque
  asperiores accusantium ipsum quo atque blanditiis libero modi numquam ipsa? Enim fuga possimus facilis numquam sunt perspiciatis aspernatur unde, accusantium ea, voluptatibus officiis eligendi. Enim eum neque quaerat cum consequuntur esse blanditiis
  quos deserunt quisquam earum, laudantium officiis ipsa expedita aut distinctio dolorem nihil velit est? Exercitationem commodi quam hic quibusdam quos iusto blanditiis dolorem? Nulla, a ipsam quam dignissimos veniam fuga provident hic dolore eum exercitationem
  incidunt autem sequi ut consequuntur saepe amet soluta laborum repellendus accusantium. Quibusdam quod molestias delectus illo distinctio quis, atque aliquid fuga, recusandae repudiandae fugiat? Illum expedita quo at, doloribus architecto officiis eveniet
  aliquid voluptas dolore officia in, culpa vel! Consequatur quaerat odio maiores voluptatum tempora, ex, obcaecati iusto amet ea incidunt porro. Autem consectetur beatae non, quae ad dignissimos quidem dolorem itaque ipsam adipisci ipsum rem delectus
  quibusdam nesciunt quo odio minima magni libero eligendi at asperiores? Excepturi, labore! Repudiandae libero est vel quas harum facere recusandae omnis doloribus distinctio iusto accusantium modi laudantium eaque repellat, dolorum vero, aut ipsam eligendi!
  Asperiores error recusandae vitae et doloribus, necessitatibus ducimus sapiente eligendi obcaecati? Commodi harum excepturi, iure facere mollitia, obcaecati, sunt eos odio perspiciatis consequuntur deleniti molestias quibusdam voluptatem illo quasi
  voluptas quidem recusandae! Voluptatibus repellendus assumenda cupiditate ipsum corporis, quae provident itaque adipisci magni ipsam sunt doloremque error repellat quam! Dolorum molestias deleniti quia quis voluptates ipsam expedita, laboriosam sequi
  repudiandae ipsa eveniet alias, obcaecati ullam? Sapiente consequatur assumenda praesentium tempore sequi dolorem, ullam rerum quas laudantium ex ipsam vero, non commodi nihil a ipsum maxime id incidunt ratione in accusantium aperiam voluptates! Suscipit
  fuga ipsam, accusantium maiores nobis tempora nesciunt culpa. Esse, illum vitae error natus unde nobis asperiores placeat, neque corrupti possimus, saepe voluptatibus. Impedit corporis, quod repellat voluptatem nulla quae voluptate rerum ea fugit quaerat
  nam expedita eius iure, consequuntur perspiciatis harum, nisi aperiam neque molestias magnam consectetur sit eligendi? Amet, optio eligendi repellendus, culpa magni ullam pariatur voluptatum harum itaque deserunt beatae ducimus exercitationem officiis
  dignissimos aliquid aliquam? Sunt officia accusamus veniam hic animi similique recusandae facilis, vero cumque ad enim nostrum ea voluptate in tempore! Doloremque optio dolore sapiente repellendus. Enim sunt et, minima assumenda sapiente voluptas fugiat
  nihil quam modi magnam vitae, aliquid mollitia commodi quia, eum laborum non aut vero id. Architecto officia nam nisi aliquam voluptate ullam exercitationem quos quam beatae quod dicta saepe nobis voluptatum, sequi laboriosam deserunt reprehenderit,
  corrupti excepturi asperiores quibusdam eos hic, sunt aut sit? Nostrum numquam repudiandae similique, voluptate voluptatem cupiditate veniam at, nulla consectetur ullam pariatur. Eveniet ea quod quae, facilis esse doloremque corporis voluptatem soluta
  hic rem quas officiis unde reprehenderit enim. Ratione nemo magni maiores minus totam, omnis, magnam aliquam repellat ut veritatis pariatur odit numquam consectetur, ducimus eos. Necessitatibus non porro nihil eius atque. Quasi nesciunt quia tenetur
  nulla ea error porro! Labore, fuga ipsa esse at consequatur laborum, optio eum ab hic perferendis sunt corporis ratione. Voluptatibus voluptas et tempora eius, cum explicabo, minima dignissimos nobis nisi nostrum vero! Dolorem repudiandae expedita harum
  tempora. Dignissimos nihil ipsam quas vitae reiciendis officiis numquam doloribus harum. Dicta obcaecati tempora quos eos nam, totam, earum accusamus cumque reprehenderit dolore ea illum? Minima quo, minus voluptatum veritatis tempore porro eum consequuntur
  dolorem reiciendis ab. Animi autem laudantium enim unde expedita fugit, culpa hic repellendus nihil natus magnam nostrum, esse voluptate labore nesciunt est obcaecati quod itaque rem a, incidunt possimus reiciendis? Reprehenderit repudiandae ex, dolores
  sit tempore aliquid assumenda maxime qui similique, perferendis quidem delectus quam veniam aliquam expedita necessitatibus quasi impedit amet neque fugit? Atque quas mollitia voluptatum sunt aspernatur earum perspiciatis enim magni, distinctio quidem,
  incidunt natus magnam officia modi unde amet eum voluptatem ratione. Illo soluta ullam et explicabo. Iusto, voluptatem iste ad modi vel optio reprehenderit dolores veniam necessitatibus esse distinctio nobis, quis aspernatur architecto fugit voluptatibus
  ipsam natus. Dolorem molestias aut natus pariatur sed cupiditate eligendi aliquid asperiores nam voluptas, repellendus commodi nobis assumenda quasi? Dolorem sit est id quam nulla excepturi labore obcaecati quaerat animi pariatur culpa aut cumque mollitia
  eligendi sint rem a tenetur cum quidem eos voluptatum, nesciunt officia nam nobis. Dolor totam, hic cum molestiae similique sed nesciunt, corporis dicta pariatur nisi adipisci distinctio quam ea commodi molestias! Eligendi, labore, laborum velit dolorem
  fugit ex maiores veritatis, autem a error unde alias magnam. Harum doloribus quam debitis eligendi. Atque alias et eius? Quisquam magnam eligendi perspiciatis eaque dolorum dolores rerum accusamus repudiandae, modi ullam ut numquam reprehenderit expedita
  explicabo, inventore enim unde at dignissimos, laudantium blanditiis molestias repellendus. Iure, porro. Consequuntur enim quo quae unde? Ducimus enim, sit dolor neque aperiam nobis aliquid labore nostrum perferendis, deserunt molestias provident. Voluptas
  iste assumenda nam nemo? Cum minima quae voluptatum hic expedita sed culpa iste officia ipsam non? Expedita magnam accusantium nemo velit quam amet maiores illum corporis obcaecati! Reprehenderit in corrupti sequi esse incidunt id, suscipit nihil iure
  qui quae laborum natus impedit voluptas fugiat odit itaque, cupiditate similique sed voluptates iste quidem quaerat, labore nostrum. Quaerat dolorem minima in velit doloremque, aliquid optio fuga maiores necessitatibus labore laudantium temporibus ullam
  dicta facilis sed rerum. Ea nobis architecto sed deserunt aut ullam accusantium voluptate voluptatum et. Ducimus eius dignissimos enim velit dicta totam, quisquam veniam iste, et labore voluptates quia voluptate sit sunt, molestiae iusto eveniet exercitationem
  temporibus expedita tempore quidem quibusdam inventore! Hic reiciendis eveniet minus facilis atque error optio eligendi distinctio rem ab assumenda ipsum commodi sit, itaque, voluptates illo repudiandae maxime ratione neque! Saepe, illo quod cum illum
  fuga nam quis reiciendis labore, incidunt vero assumenda delectus deleniti in perspiciatis ad natus! Quibusdam fugit laboriosam excepturi officia culpa alias eos reprehenderit est. Labore soluta maxime exercitationem rerum consectetur in itaque ad.
  Fuga eius nisi commodi ratione deleniti quis consequatur! Magnam nulla reprehenderit soluta, quaerat quos quas sed autem consequatur praesentium doloremque facere possimus, omnis quo tempore rerum recusandae. Nam veniam quis eos repellat labore illum
  aperiam? Cupiditate dolore qui autem atque dignissimos rerum tempore voluptate fugit repellat obcaecati nobis repudiandae voluptatem, sed ipsum sint odit ullam aut dolorem, maxime, labore quidem tempora. Deserunt beatae laboriosam doloremque facilis
  nam. Veritatis, quaerat ex? Omnis voluptatum distinctio ipsam et, ad, accusantium animi unde explicabo iste quis eius porro. Mollitia tempora blanditiis laudantium asperiores facilis amet ut, voluptatibus aut odio, nesciunt dolorum architecto, repudiandae
  provident aspernatur. Sint?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias perferendis quos soluta animi, assumenda, non officia nam similique sapiente aliquid cumque ad est optio doloribus ipsa ipsum. Omnis accusantium ea dignissimos
  pariatur, commodi minus porro sit voluptate, tempora, incidunt nobis explicabo! Iure inventore eius deserunt ab corporis voluptas quo fuga molestiae vel culpa veritatis deleniti delectus ipsum dolor itaque alias sapiente, exercitationem quas sunt? Expedita
  asperiores, quaerat rem corporis nihil vel voluptatum distinctio. Aliquam maxime magni numquam, aspernatur facilis alias ullam nesciunt, deserunt consequatur deleniti nisi saepe suscipit, quidem cum odio sed voluptatibus. Nulla dicta unde magnam qui
  ratione exercitationem nam veniam dolorum similique blanditiis quasi, possimus, placeat nostrum obcaecati reprehenderit deserunt excepturi, quo nihil. Cupiditate, pariatur consequuntur? Dignissimos quae nisi id maiores provident quasi ratione totam
  quaerat, placeat laudantium architecto sapiente temporibus aperiam impedit officia possimus explicabo officiis quia quis! Et exercitationem aut eius officiis quidem dolorem repellendus error adipisci at voluptatum doloribus quibusdam eligendi impedit
  nam accusamus labore consectetur earum, atque autem laborum dolorum animi? Numquam laborum impedit obcaecati eveniet labore repellendus deserunt sunt eligendi architecto odio maxime incidunt aut ut dignissimos veritatis autem illum delectus, nesciunt
  provident ducimus earum! Nam eius iste harum deserunt saepe rerum dolorum quisquam consectetur. Sapiente facere distinctio ipsa quasi unde eos nobis culpa? Architecto officiis a consequuntur illum labore illo nisi reiciendis tempore eos neque voluptatem
  ipsa aperiam obcaecati hic recusandae ut sit, dolores in deserunt cupiditate animi dignissimos? Accusantium recusandae id officia necessitatibus fugit cum ullam nulla perspiciatis nihil magnam, aspernatur quod maxime, ab quidem voluptatum possimus nam
  voluptates incidunt rem error minus dolorum facere temporibus. Saepe sed quaerat nobis omnis ex excepturi fugiat voluptate, ad sint. Sint, accusantium ipsam officia ad sapiente non nemo tempora optio facere eos odio qui quos quae neque in consequuntur,
  veritatis similique cupiditate. Illum iste voluptatum aliquid quia numquam? Maiores quaerat, expedita mollitia eius placeat sit dolorum eum sed omnis facilis explicabo! Placeat, quo eligendi ipsum assumenda, qui deleniti modi ratione perspiciatis alias
  voluptate perferendis dicta, neque maxime cupiditate vel reprehenderit excepturi. Sit reprehenderit ex reiciendis, ea corporis pariatur natus porro voluptatibus quisquam ad quas veniam impedit, quod harum veritatis dolorem libero earum tempora, corrupti
  repudiandae temporibus nostrum labore error mollitia. Numquam expedita itaque incidunt magni enim quo consequuntur qui ab repudiandae, fugit ipsa impedit architecto aliquam blanditiis aspernatur nemo repellat accusantium, voluptate a exercitationem
  libero ullam? Eveniet provident cum quia impedit sed ad doloribus rem repellendus pariatur! Accusantium modi facere quos. Minima aut ad vero sint doloremque quaerat soluta voluptatibus, pariatur autem repudiandae maiores facilis iste molestiae numquam
  ab beatae dolore! Perferendis tempore aperiam explicabo rerum deleniti veniam ut, iste nostrum dolore eius quae dolores error, doloribus reiciendis, cumque incidunt. Unde, ducimus! Dolorum distinctio ratione cumque exercitationem minima accusantium
  est, ipsa deleniti maiores vero, sunt, error ipsam quos vitae explicabo magni repudiandae illo porro omnis impedit esse quis aperiam amet eum. Dolorum eos tempora, odit in et dignissimos voluptas dolorem iusto quod aperiam cum facere enim distinctio
  est mollitia aliquam nam eveniet! Itaque, omnis!
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Или этот же код на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/YzKdyrp)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]